# Get value of text (with no tag) in scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am trying to get the value of text (with no tag like `<p>`,`<a>` etc.) from this link

https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/us/donald-trump-boris-johnson-talk-5g-and-trade-ahead-of-g7-white-house/articleshow/70504270.cms

So far I have used scrapy shell to get their values using this code

```
 item=response.xpath("//div[@class='Normal']/text()").extract()
```

Or

```
item=response.css('arttextxml *::text').extract()
```

The problem is that I am getting values when I use these commands in Scrapy Shell but when I use in my scrapy spyder file it return null value

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Kindly provide code of your scrapy spyder file. Without it can't tell what's wrong with this.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k36ln1iWXPBIhozoklc67JlEiwqZjNxn

Comment: Try writing `response.text` to a file in both cases (shell, spider), see if you can spot any difference. Maybe you are getting a different response in your spider due to detected activity or some request aspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple problems with your code.

First, it is messy. Second, the CSS selector you are using to get all link to the news articles, giving the same URL more than once. Third, as per your code, in `scrapy.Request` method calling, you used `self.parseNews` as a callback method, which is not even available in the whole file.

I have fixed your code on some level and right now, I am not facing any issue with it.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class TimesofindiaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'timesofindia'
    allowed_domains = ["timesofindia.indiatimes.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/World"]
    base_url = "https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/"

    def parse(self, response):        
        for urls in response.css('div.top-newslist > ul > li'):
            url = urls.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(self.base_url + url, callback = self.parse_save)

    def parse_save(self, response):
        print(response.xpath("//div[@class='Normal']/text()").extract())
```

Comment: Thanks you soo much , that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I write a simple spider for you. You get your desired output.
Also show your code so i can correct you what you are doing wrong.

## Scraper

```
import scrapy


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['timesofindia.indiatimes.com']
    start_urls = ['https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/us/donald-trump-boris-johnson-talk-5g-and-trade-ahead-of-g7-white-house/articleshow/70504270.cms']

    def parse(self, response):
        item = response.xpath('//div[@class="Normal"]/text()').extract()

        yield{'Item':item}
```

Comment: I Tried that but it did not work 
here is my spyder file 
drive.google.com/open?id=1k36ln1iWXPBIhozoklc67JlEiwqZjNxn